# How to add a callback function to an asynchronous job in powershell and get return data

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I've been searching around the internet and combining lots of different pieces of code, but I'm just not succeeding at creating a callback for my asynchronous job.

The idea is that I want to run multiple jobs, and using the callback methods I will be able to parse the output from the different jobs to change certain states and output in the main script.

Currently I have this, and although the event gets called, I'm unable to get the actual output.
What am I missing here?

```
$rsPool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,2)
$rsPool.Open();

$WebRequest = {
    param($url)
    return Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url)
}

$handler = {
  Write-Host "event called";
  Write-Host $_
}

$jobs = @()

$PSinstance = [powershell]::Create();
$PSinstance.AddScript($WebRequest).AddArgument("https://google.com")
$PSinstance.RunspacePool = $rsPool
$jobs += $PSinstance.BeginInvoke()

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $PSinstance -EventName InvocationStateChanged -Action $handler;

#$PSinstance | Get-member -MemberType Event

while($jobs.isCompleted -contains $false) {
    Start-Sleep 1
}

$rsPool.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the Invoke method, and the Event registerer to pass a parameter that contains the output.

Although this is probably not the cleanest method, it does work for me (with some checks in place that the data isn't accessed before it's actually available of course.

```
$Object = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[psobject]';

$jobs += $PSinstance.BeginInvoke($Object, $Object);

Add-Member -InputObject $PSinstance -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EventSubscriber -Value (
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $PSinstance -EventName InvocationStateChanged -MessageData $Object -Action {
        # Ignore initial state change on startup
        if ($event.InvocationStateInfo.State -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationState]::Running) {
            return;
        }

        Write-Host "event called";
        Write-Host $Object.StatusCode;
    }
);

# Can be accessed after the invoke has finished.
Write-Host "The result is: $Object.StatusCode";
```

Answer (score 1):

As an **alternative to using the fairly complex [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation)**, if this is just about running the web requests in parallel and it is acceptable to synchronously wait for them to finish,
**[`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object)** - available in **PowerShell v7+** - offers a simple solution:

```
# Uses threads to run two Invoke-WebRequest calls in parallel,
# synchronously waits for both to finish and collects the responses.
$responses = 'https://google.com', 'http://example.org' | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_
}
```

Instead of waiting synchronously, you can also use the **`-AsJob` switch** to have *job objects* returned<sup>[1]</sup>, asynchronously, which you can later manage with the regular `*-Job` cmdlets (`Wait-Job`, `Receive-Job`, ...):

```
# Uses threads to run two Invoke-WebRequest calls in parallel.
# Asynchronously returns job objects that can be monitored later.
$jobs = 'https://google.com', 'http://example.org' | ForEach-Object -AsJob -Parallel {
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_
}

# ... do other things

# Now wait synchronously (though you could poll the state instead).
# and output the responses.
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

**In earlier PowerShell versions** you can use the **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet** (comes with v6+, installable via `Install-Module ThreadJob` in earlier versions)<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
$jobs = 'https://google.com', 'http://example.org' | ForEach-Object {
  $uri = $_
  Start-ThreadJob { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $using:uri }
}

# ... do other things

# Now wait synchronously (though you could poll the state in a loop instead)
# and output the responses.
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

---

Note: While you could also use regular *child-process*-based *background jobs*, created with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job), the *thread*-based options above perform much better - see [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).

---

<sup>[1] Instances of `[System.Management.Automation.PSTasks.PSTaskJob]`, a not currently documented type that derives from [`System.Management.Automation.Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Job), which ensures that instances can be used with the `*-Job` cmdlets.</sup>

<sup>[2] `Start-ThreadJob` returns instances of `[ThreadJob.ThreadJob]`, a not currently documented type that derives from [`System.Management.Automation.Job2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Job2), which in turn derives from [`System.Management.Automation.Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Job)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

`

```
$rsPool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,2)
$rsPool.Open();

$WebRequest = {
    param($url)
    return Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url)
}


$jobs = @()

$PSinstance = [powershell]::Create();
$PSinstance.AddScript($WebRequest).AddArgument("https://google.com")
$PSinstance.RunspacePool = $rsPool
$Jobs += [PSCustomObject]@{ Pipe = $PSinstance; Status = $PSinstance.BeginInvoke() }

$results=@()
while ($Jobs.Status -ne $null)
{
    start-sleep -s 1
    write-host "." -nonewline -fore cyan
    foreach ($completedjob in $Jobs|?{ $_.Status.IsCompleted -eq $true })
    {
        $results+=$completedjob.Pipe.EndInvoke($completedjob.Status)
        $completedjob.Status = $null
    }
}

$rsPool.close();

$results|out-host
```

`

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't use the callback function and wouldn't work for me as I need to parse output data on the fly from different jobs