# Multithreading a powershell script and challenges

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I have developed a script which does a lot of processing for a front end tool, now I am attempting to have the script run with multiple threads. It interacts a lot with SQL databases, this should not be a problem for multithreading as the database transactions are very short lived, and the queries well optimised.

**what is the issue ?**

```
#.\tester.ps1  -servers (1,'Server1',3,1),(2,'Server2',3,1) -output_folder 'C:\temp'


param ([array[]]$servers),$output_folder

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $servers.Count; $i++)
{
    
    $myserverid = $servers[$i][0]
    $myservername = $servers[$i][1]
    $mylocationid = $servers[$i][2]
    $myappid = $servers[$i][3]

    write-output " $myserverid  and $myservername and $mylocationid and $myappid"
    invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$myservername" -query "select top 10 name from sysobjects"  -Database  "master" 

}
```

The script file above will gets passed an array of servers and currently it will loop through the array one by one. A way for me to make the process faster is to run the script in parallel /run the script with multiple threads.

**Research**

I have looked at a technet script on https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-a-PowerShell-script-991c8a42

Its not quite the same as my array is not just a list of servers, there will be other parameters sent with it.

**What am I after**

A way or pointer to make the script be able to run in parallel or an example using the provided script above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Threads are pretty simple in powershell 7 with foreach-object -parallel.

Comment: Using Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core, running actions in parallel is a well documented, much talked about use-case. A quick web search will show you how to do this.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825731/45375) for two thread-based ways to run PowerShell code in parallel (I would avoid Workflows (obsolescent) and child-process-based background jobs (slow)). If you have trouble adapting the techniques there, you can ask a follow-up question with the specific problems you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Extending my comment. In PowerShell v5, use [Jobs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20parallel%20jobs%27&t=h_&ia=web) and [Workflows for Parallel](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20workflow%20parrallel%27&t=h_&ia=web) use cases.

```
# Example using parallel jobs
$start = Get-Date

# get all hotfixes
$task1 = { Get-Hotfix }

# get all scripts in your profile
$task2 = { Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq Running }

# parse log file
$task3 = { Get-Content -Path $env:windir\windowsupdate.log | Where-Object { $_ -like '*successfully installed*' } }

# run 2 tasks in the background, and 1 in the foreground task
$job1 =  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task1 
$job2 =  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task2 
$result3 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $task3

# wait for the remaining tasks to complete (if not done yet)
$null = Wait-Job -Job $job1, $job2

# now they are done, get the results
$result1 = Receive-Job -Job $job1
$result2 = Receive-Job -Job $job2

# discard the jobs
Remove-Job -Job $job1, $job2

$end = Get-Date



# Example, using WorkFlow
workflow Test-WFConnection
{
    param
    (
        [string[]]$Computers
    )

    foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers)
    {
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Windows PowerShell Workflows were introduced in v3, but never really took off. Given that they're [no longer available in PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/), where all future development effort will go, I think it's fair to call it an obsolescent technology.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up here, due to the nature of what I am doing. I need to loop over a list of SQL instances, the workflow option is better suited, but please advice if thats not the case. Looking at the structure of jobs, I am not sure if it can work.