# Error with powershell workflow and custom classes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to improve the performance of a release tool, the way it currently works is via a loop which loops through each server one at a time and takes an awful long time as its connecting to SQL databases etc and doing a lot of script running, I have read up about Ps workflows and I feel its what might work in my particular scenario, but I have got 2 issues here.

Here is what I have learnt so far.

**This works**

```
class Deployment_List {
    [int] $serverid; [string] $servername;[int] $locationid; [int] $appid
    Deployment_List($propValueArray) {
      $this.serverid = $propValueArray[0]; $this.servername = $propValueArray[1]; $this.locationid = $propValueArray[2]; $this.appid = $propValueArray[3]
    }
  }
  
[Deployment_List[]] ((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))
```

It gives me a visual representation of how I want to process the data, but I am having issues accessing the data the way I want to process it.

What I want is something like this, processing each item in the array means that I need

```
1,"Server1",3,1
1 = serverid
Server1 = servername
3 = locationid
1 = appid
```

An idea

```
    class Deployment_List {
        [int] $serverid; [string] $servername;[int] $locationid; [int] $appid
        Deployment_List($propValueArray) {
          $this.serverid = $propValueArray[0]; $this.servername = $propValueArray[1]; $this.locationid = $propValueArray[2]; $this.appid = $propValueArray[3]
        }
      }
      
      # Use an array cast to construct [Deployment_List] instances.
      # Note the need for (...) around the array, because casts have high
      # precedence in PowerShell.
          [Deployment_List[]] ((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))

          $x = [Deployment_List[]] ((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))

#      [Deployment_List[]]

    foreach  ($items in $x)
    {

        if ([array].locationid -eq 2)
        {
            $inputfile = 'G:\release\releasev1.sql'
        }
        else 
        {
            $inputfile = 'G:\release\releasev2.sql'
        }

        if ([array].appid -eq 1)
        {
            $db_name = 'vax'
        }
        else{

            $db_name = 'users'

        }

        invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $servername -Database 'vax' -InputFile $inputfile

    }
```

The code doesn't work I wanted to explain what I am trying to achieve, but you get the idea of what I am trying to do, I am looping through each constructor and using that to make decisions within the if statement, if I had a normal array, I would not have access to the other values like the locationid, appid at thesame time which I require.

How can I achieve this please ?

The second part of the problem is that even if the above works, I have read up about workflows and it could speed up the performance of the tool. I tried to use the syntax below without much luck.

```
workflow Release {
  param($serverlist)

    class Deployment_List {
        [int] $serverid; [string] $servername;[int] $locationid; [int] $appid
        Deployment_List($propValueArray) {
          $this.serverid = $propValueArray[0]; $this.servername = $propValueArray[1]; $this.locationid = $propValueArray[2]; $this.appid = $propValueArray[3]
        }
      }
      
          $X = [Deployment_List[]] $serverlist 

          foreach  ($items in $x)
          {
      
              if ([array].locationid -eq 2)
              {
                  $inputfile = 'G:\release\releasev1.sql'
              }
              else 
              {
                  $inputfile = 'G:\release\releasev2.sql'
              }
      
              if ([array].appid -eq 1)
              {
                  $db_name = 'vax'
              }
              else{
      
                  $db_name = 'users'
      
              }
      
              invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $servername -Database 'vax' -InputFile $inputfile
      
          }
       
}

Release '((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))'
```

The server list comes from an external source in would be in the format `'((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))'`

I have tried various methods but its leading to a lot of frustration hence why I have turned here for help.

Comment: You need to go back and learn the basics of powershell. [array] is not your data. If($something = ‘something’) is an assignment, not a comparison. You are way over complicating it trying to pass data around as arrays when they should be objects.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I explained earlier that [array] is clearly not the data, I simply was trying to explain what I am trying to achieve  hence why I coded it like the above.

Comment: Yeah that doesn’t help anyone.

Comment: Note that Windows PowerShell workflows were introduced in v3, but never really took off. Given that they're [no longer available in PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/), where all future development effort will go, I think it's fair to call it an obsolescent technology.

Comment: `[array].locationid` -> `$item.locationid` - `[array]` is a _type literal_ and describes a data _type_, not an individual object.

Comment: The nature of hte processing means that I cant use jobs, secondly its Powershell v5, so cant use foreach parallel either.

Comment: @user5544: If you want user to be notified of follow-up comments, you must @-mention them (as I have done here to notify you). For thread-based parallelism in Windows PowerShell (v5.1), use `Start-ThreadJob`, via the `ThreadJob` module that you can easily install with `Install-Module ThreadJob` (they're also a type of _job_, in PowerShell terms, but unlike `Start-Job` launched jobs, they are based on _threads_ rather than _child processes_) - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825731/45375) that I previously pointed you to.